# SQL help selecting customer information from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an assignment where I had to create two tables named **Customer** and **Address**.  These tables are located within a database called HandsOnOne.

**Customer** has columns titled:
`CustomerID`, `CustomerName`, `CustomerAddressID`

**Address** has columns titled:
`AddressID`, `Street`, `City`, `State`, `ZipCode`

There is a foreign key relationship in which `AddressID` in the **Address** Table is the primary key and `CustomerAddressID` in the **Customer** Table is the foreign key.

I used the following code to insert values into each table:

```
USE HandsOnOne;

INSERT INTO Address (AddressID, Street, City, State, ZipCode)    
VALUES (1, '2400 Broadway Drive', 'Missoula', 'MT', '59802'),
(2, '320 21st Street', 'Billings', 'MT', '59101'),    
(3, '439 Skyline Blvd', 'Denver', 'CO', '80002'),    
(4, '56 Park Avenue', 'New York', 'NY', '10001');

USE HandsOnOne;

INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddressID)
VALUES (1, 'Western Supply Company', 1),    
(2, 'Nick Harper', 3),
(3, 'Alice Harper', 3),
(4, 'Abacus Consulting', 4);
```

From there, I have to sort based on certain specifications.  The first specification was to list all customers with city and state sorted ascending by `ZipCode` then ascending by `CustomerName`.

Here is the code I used for this part:

```
USE HandsOnOne;

SELECT CustomerName, City, State    
FROM Customer, Address
ORDER BY ZipCode ASC, CustomerName ASC;
```

When I execute this code, my return is 16 items instead of 4.  Somehow, each customer is being assigned each address, giving me 4 items at each address.

The next question asks me to list the `Street`, `City`, `State` and `ZipCode` of all address without a customer associated with them.
  This query should return the address of *320 21st St Billings*, *MT 59101* because its `AddressID` value is *2* and there is no `CustomerAddressID` value of *2* in the **Address** table.  However, I do not receive any results when I execute this query.

I have verified that there is a foreign key relationship.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since JohnHC has already given the answer, I will add this: Following diagram helped me a lot when I started using joins :) http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-bC-tThYQxxU/UZy6wVYiZeI/AAAAAAAAAjM/A18S8PkK6Uo/s1600/SQL+JOINS.PNG

Comment: @DenStudent I have a similar one on my wall

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Gosh this sure looks familiar...http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1821764-3077-1.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You aren't restricting your join. Also, the implicit join is no longer supported in most DBMS (especially recent versions of SQL server), so an explicit `Inner Join` is best.

Try this:

```
select CustomerName, City, State
from Customer 
inner join Address 
    on AddressID = CustomerAddressID -- I assume this is the foreign key
order by ZipCode asc, CustomerName asc
```

Ah, question 2 (missed that due to formatting)

```
select A1.*
from Address A1
left join Customer C2
    on A1.AddressID = C2.CustomerAddressID
where C2.CustomerAddressID is null
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!  The join needed to be stated explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd question: use `NOT EXISTS` to get all addresses without a customer. See below:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Address A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM   Customer C
                  WHERE  C.CustomerAddressID = A.AddressID)
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the assignment is to learn about joins... But this is absolutely the correct solution for the second problem, just maybe not the answer you need.

Comment: I find no hint in the 2nd question that the solution must be using a join.

Comment: Yeh, but look at the context. Q1 is about an inner join, Q2 is solvable via a join. Hey, I'm not saying you're wrong. Yours is the most efficient solution. I'm just saying that using a join is more likely to be the answer to the assignement (having written a few of these myself).

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the help!  Both answers are acceptable for my class since both of those methods were covered in this lesson

Comment: If you like the answers, please do not hesitate to upvote :-)